# Como forçar a atualização de alguns valores quando utilizo o window.history.back() do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

É possível forçar a atualização de alguns valores da minha View mesmo quando utilizo o `window.history.back()` do Javascript? Meu exemplo:

No meu layout, tenho um icone de carrinho com o numero de itens dentro do mesmo. Quando eu adiciono um item ao carrinho com esse código:

```
function AddCartItem(obj) {
obj.SelectedResolutionID = $('input[name=ImageResolutionID]:checked').val();

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Ajax/AddCart",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
})
    .done(function (obj) {
        if (obj.response) {
            setTimeout(function () { window.history.back() }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

e retorno para a página anterior utilizando `window.history.back()` como escrito no código acima. Porém esse comando possivelmente recupera do cache a página anterior, e o ícone com o numero de itens não atualiza ! é possível eu forçar essa atualização e manter o comando `window.history.back()` ?

Eu utilizo ASP.NET MVC5, o numero de itens do meu carrinho vem de uma classe de controle de cookies, segue o código:

```
<li>@CartCookieController.ReturnCartProductsCount()</li>
```

Comment: Você conseguirá fazer isso criando uma forma de armazenamento do lado cliente, como localStorage e chamar uma função JS que irá atualizar o número no ícone do carrinho sempre que uma página for aberta, seja pelo `history.back()` ou não.

Answer (score 0):

Pode armazenar a informacao utilizando cookies.

```
<input id="backbutton" type="button" value="Back" onClick="atualizarCarrinho()"/>

function atualizarCarrinho()
{
 document.cookie = name+"=index%3d1; expires=whenever;path=/";
 window.history.back()
}
```